# Template instantiation by non type parameter

Tags: c++, templates, instantiation, constexpr, non-type

```
template<typename T, T MIN , T MAX>
struct Range
{
    const T min;
    const T max;
    Range():min(MIN),max(MAX){};
};

template<>
struct Range<float32, MIN, MAX>
{
    typedef float32 T;
    const T min;
    const  T max;
    inline Range():min(MIN),max(MAX){};
};

struct InvalidObject
{
      const Range<uint8, 0U ,2U> numOfPoints ;
};
```

I want to make template to range parameters of InvalidObject same as shown in struct InvalidObject.
Compiler error in this struct `struct Range<float32, MIN, MAX>`
i want to do this because i cannot make instantiation on range template with float.
Please advice if this applicable .

Comment: Floating point types are not allowed as non-type template parameters, only integrals. IIRC, C++20 will allow them tho.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I'd expect this to require something like `template<float32 MIN, float32 MAX> struct Range<float32, MIN, MAX>`, since otherwise I think `MIN` and `MAX` are undefined. (Even after assuming that we can use floating point non-type arguments.)